# How to tap button to open URL with the UIButton in the Table View cells?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, web, button

Stackoverflow user.

I know that cells can open URL, otherwise Button may not open inside the cells.
let's imagine I am create a sale stuff on the app. I want to tap that button not cells.

resource code:

You have create two swift folders called DCCMerchViewController and MerchTableViewCell.

Connect the MerchTableViewCell from storyboard (based on the tableview cells)

class MerchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
// Image
@IBOutlet weak var Merch_Image: UIImageView!

// Title
@IBOutlet weak var Merch_Title: UILabel!

// Price
@IBOutlet weak var Merch_Price: UILabel!

// Purchase
@IBAction func PurchaseMerch(_ sender: Any, linker: String) {

     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: linker)! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}
```

now, You have connect to DCCMerchViewController from Storyboard (Based on table view controller)

class DCCMerchViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var MerchTableView: UITableView!

}
```

and create a array to allow calling array into the cells by use IndexPath.row.

````
 class DCCMerchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MerchTableView: UITableView!


    let imageMerch = ["image1", "image2"]

    let titleMerch = ["Title1", "Title2"]

    let buyLink = ["www.link.com", www.link1.com]

    let priceMerch = ["44.99", "38.99", "23.99"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


     }

    }


And add the extension after class Storetableview (notice make sure Table View Controller connect to this UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.) 

``` extension DCCMerchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // Image
        return titleMerch.count


    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 128
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let merchCell = MerchTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MerchCells", for: indexPath) as? MerchTableViewCell

        // Image
        merchCell?.Merch_Image.image = UIImage(named: imageMerch[indexPath.row])

        // Title
        merchCell?.Merch_Title.text = titleMerch[indexPath.row]

        // Price
        merchCell?.Merch_Price.text = "Price: $\( priceMerch[indexPath.row])"

        // Purchase
        merchCell?.PurchaseMerch( AnyIndex.self, linker: "\(buyLink[indexPath.row])")
       // Kinda issues is merchCells cause this cells to open web othewise not tap those buttons... huh?

        return merchCell!

    }



 }
````

Now have someone know how to stop open URL when tap cells, I am try to get open url by use button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create outlet for the button inside the cell then in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.btn.addTarget(self,#selector(clicked),for:touchUpInside)
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
```

---

Add this inside the vc

```
@objc func clicked (_ btn:UIButton) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:buyLink[btn.tag])!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```